# Ajax is sending multiple/duplicating calls on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am fetching my content with an AJAX call, for any reason the AJAX calls are duplicating itself on every new click.

I already tried different on click events I found from other threads here on Stackoverflow. But unfortunately this is also not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var startModal = $('#modal-container').data('modal');

  if (startModal) {
    openUrlInModal(startModal, $('#modal-container'));
  }

  //AJAX Function to fetch project content
  function openUrlInModal(url, target){
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(response) {
        $(target).append(url);
        $('#modal-container').html(response);
      }
    });
  }

  // Adds content to the modal on click

  $('.load').on("click",function(e) {

    //History Pushstate
    fetchedProjectUrl = $(this).data('url');
    window.history.pushState(null, null, fetchedProjectUrl);

    //Call Ajax Function
    openUrlInModal(fetchedProjectUrl, $('#modal-container'));

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  //Hitting Back Button
  $(window).on("popstate", function(){
    //history.pushState(null, null, "");
    function empty(){
    $('#modal-container').empty();
    }
    setTimeout(empty, 300);
  });
});
```

Comment: You're probably calling the function more than once. Is there any more code?

Comment: A lot of times doing `.off().on("click",`.... helps when I am seeing multiple events firing.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible multiple click events are firing when you click that button. You can see all the fired events in the Event Handler area of the dev tools.

This will remove all event handlers:

```
$(element).off().on('click', function() {
    // function body
});
```

To only remove registered 'click' event handlers:

```
$(element).off('click').on('click', function() {
    // function body
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. Unfortunately this isn't working either for me. The link is now only working on the third click.

Comment: You might also want to try putting these lines at the beginning of the click function rather than end:
`e.preventDefault();  
 e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: hmm still the same problem :( the console is still duplication the calls

Comment: Can you make your jQuery selector more specific? With an ID possibly?